# Adobe Edge - get DIV inside Symbol

Tags: jquery, css, html, symbols, adobe-edge

In adobe edge, if you want to change the background color of a symbol, you use:

```
sym.$('Blob1').css({"background-color":"#DDD"});
```

But if I want to change the CSS of a div INSIDE the symbol, what should I write?

Comment: or you can use closest http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Do you know that `$('Blob1')` selects `<Blob1>`?

Comment: @undefined No it doesn't - not in context of `sym`. I know it looks like that, and for pure JQuery that would be the case - but `sym` closure allows for a bit different "syntax". As usual Adobe changes just enough to break compatibility, courtesy their slightly braindead developers.

Answer (score 1):

```
sym.$('Blob1').find('div').css(...)
```

Comment: @SylvainVansteelandt what about `$(sym.$('Blob1')).find('div')`?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert here but I've been able to do this using a structure like 
`sym.$('Blob1').$('inner_div').css({"background-color":"#DDD"});`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the css of a div inside a symbol, you should access that div, then its style properties.

for example, to set the color attribute to red, it might look like:

```
$('#id_of_innerdiv').css('background-color', '#ddd');
```

note: this relies on the jquery library that comes with adobe edge.

Answer (score 0):

`Blob1` is actually a child node of the symbol referenced and not the symbol's own div. The result of `sym.$('Blob1')` is a jQuery object so you're able to use `children()`, `find()` or whatever traversal method you like to go further down. If the child is actually a nested symbol though, you're better off traversing with `getSymbol()`.

If by any chance you did want to get directly at a symbol's jQuery object, it's just `sym.element`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sym.getSymbol('symbolName').$('divName').css(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to give your inside div a class (for exaple ".inner_div", the C icon for class setting is located in the "properties" panel on the right side of the div title field) than do the following :

sym.$('Blob1').find('.inner_div').css({"background-color":"#DDD"});